# Will a connection always be checked in to a c3p0 connection pool, when closing the entity manager?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I was wondering, whether it really always is the case that when I close my JPA + Hibernate entity manager a connection will be checked in to a c3p0 connection pool. From the logs of my application I'm observing sometimes that this isn't always the case, i.e., the entity manager will be closed and no check in to connection pool happens afterwards. Those connections will only be destroyed when maxConnectionAge is reached. However, I think that this might be dangerous sometimes, because I'm also sometimes observing that a connection will be reutilised again, albeit the connection has nearly reached the max connection age. So I think that it might be better to not provide those connections for check out, i.e., rather prefer young connection for check out, or?

Comment: if Connections are being destroyed at maxConnectionAge, they must be checked into the pool. client-owned Connections would not be culled at maxConnectionAge. they would only be destroyed if you have unreturnedConnectionTimeout set.

Comment: ah, okay. I set the same time interval for both properties, so the connection won't be returned to the connection then (albeit I closed the entity manager ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I had the same time interval for maxConnectionAge and unreturnedConnectionTimeout. So it turns out that there where still some open connections left in the application (which are now identified and eliminated ;) ).